# Customize the display of error messages from the webform module

Tags: webforms

I am embedding the webform in drupal 6 in my home page but the error messages are shown on the webform page, is there a way to customize it so that 'on unsuccessful submission it still shows error messages on my websites home page instead of the webforms page'?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you get redirect to webform page after submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using regular expression to overwrite the form action= in the $form. This seems to be one of the only way out to stop it from redirecting to the webform node when there is an error on submission. Thanks for the views and the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Message are not disabled on home page. Please check for `$messages` if it is properly rendered in page template file. If you are using a separate template for home page then check it specially.

Comment: I think he getting redirect to webform page after submission and he want to avoid that

Comment: You are correct drupality. It is redirecting on incorrect submission and I want to avoid that , looking for an easy way to ovrerride that behavior.